# Too many requests exception on HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Tags: c#

this is quiet different than the answers given on the other questions on the stack.

i m confused why i'm getting the exception "Too many requests" when sending a GET request to the server .

the request works fine on BURP-SUIT/PostMan even without headers . and i tried to setup 10 continuous requests on Postman and i received OK status code on all of them with interval of 700 ms . even tho in c# Code i'm still getting this exception .

any help is really appreciated .

EDIT :

```
 var req = WebRequest.Create("example.com") as HttpWebRequest;
 req.Method = "GET";
 req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0";
 req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
 req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Its helpful if you can show your code, how you are setting up your requests and and how you are calling it, otherwise we cant give an informed opinion

Comment: @TheGeneral the code is just a WebClient downloading a string from the server

Comment: See: [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2)). It might be the problem here.

Comment: Is there any chance you are calling this form a loop? or its a re-entrant problem? i.e have have you logged to make absolutely sure you aren't calling this more than you think

Comment: @TheGeneral no i'm calling it one time . and the problem is not about too many requests sent to the server because i tried to setup 10 requests with 700 ms interval on postman and it worked fine

Comment: Maybe programmtically your are sending more requests than the number of requests you send using postman.

Comment: @CodingYoshi No . i'm sending only one request

Comment: Never got this error for just one request. Maybe you have un-disposed request objects left behind.

Comment: This works for us (except "example.com" isn't a valid argument). See https://dotnetfiddle.net/RGJWqd

Comment: @Jimi i tried the request on a simple console app and it does not work too

Comment: +1 no problems running the above example. Perhaps the target server (if not example.com) is rate-limiting too aggressively?

Comment: @AdamG i tried the url on the dotnetfiddle link and im still getting the exception

Comment: @AdamG i believe it something from the .net framework since sending the request using burp and postman works fine

Comment: You don't have to take my word for it. dotnetfiddle itself can run that code. If you have been doing a lot of testing against example.com, maybe they've blacklisted your IP?

Comment: @AdamG the request didn't work on the dotnetfiddle from the first try . and if my ip is blacklisted i won't get response from postman too .

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @buff - You need to post a [mcve] for us to work from. It's no good posting code that works for us. We need to see what's not working for you. Please get the code to behave the way you say it does.

Comment: I can only get a valid response from `example.com` using a SSL connection `https://www.example.com`. It streams a 2K html file (as usual, for this kind of request). For sure you can't create a WebRequest using  "example.com" as Uri. You need to post a valid (testable) example.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your request header:

```
Retry-After: 120
```

Like this on code :

```
request.Headers.Add("Retry-After", "120");
```

Comment: there is no such property on either webclient and webrequest

Comment: still getting the exception

Comment: @MohammadNikravesh - This isn't an answer. It's a suggestion with no rationale as to what it's meant to do. If you're fishing you should ask the OP to try this in a comment and then post an answer based on their response. If you know that this is the cause then please give a reason.